# PHP/HTML user-defined function

Tags: php, forms, user-defined-functions

```
<? php



function findword($string) {

  $trimmedstring = trim($string);

  $firstspace   = strpos(' ', $trimmedstring);

  $frstwrd       = substr($trimmedstring, 0, $firstspace);


  return $frstwrd;
}


? >

**< form action = "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" method= "post" >**

Word: < input type="text" name="word" /><br />

< input type="submit" name="submit" />

< /form>


< ? php

$word = (isset($_POST['word'])) ? $_POST['word'] : '' ;

if ($word) {

  echo findword($word);

}

echo findword($word);

?>
```

Submitted word: `< ?php echo $word; ?>< br />`

The purpose of this block of code is mostly to test the the user-defined function "findword()". The variable "$word" is set to the 'user input' (line 45) from the HTML form (lines 36-38) and the empty string '' if nothing has yet been entered in the form. On line 47, if a word has been entered (and it is not the empty string) it echoes the result of the function with $word passed to it. After that (line 50) I echo the function with $word passed to it without an if function, and just the variable on line 60.

The trouble with this is that, even after a value has been entered and submitted, neither line 47 nor line 50 does anything, while the last line does (and when no value has been submitted, line 47 produces the following error: "Warning: strpos(): Empty delimiter in (*the file path*) on line 12" which is the error I would have expected from passing an empty string to findword(). What should have happened is that the test value in the if formula should have evaluated to false and then skipped the body, but instead it called the function on $word (which was an empty string) and then gave an error (as it was expected to). What is also odd is that when I do submit a value, line 50 echoes the submitted value as it should, and the two previous lines do not give an error, but they don't echo anything.

The bolded line is not quite what I had in the original code, but I had to change it, and most of the rest of the code, in order for it to be displayed properly. But it should affect the answer or the problem.

Comment: `strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )` - first the haystack, then the needle!

Comment: exactly what @deceze said: You've written your code as "does this word exist in a space character". Obviously not, unless you're searching for a space character.

Comment: Maybe I should add, in summary, that the error when no value (or an empty string) was submitted probably comes from line 47, which is to be expected. The question is why, when a value is submitted (I've tried random strings of letters, all the same result) line 47 and 45 do not echo any value.

Comment: Thank you both, it's working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function, it return the first word.

```
function getFirstWord($str) {

    $firstWord = '';
    if(!empty($str)) {
        $wordArr = explode(' ', $str);
        $firstWord = $wordArr[0];
    }
    return $firstWord;
}
```